# why does a jquery trigger click not update the location.hash?

Tags: jquery

Given something like ... trigger('click')

Where the selector is a link like so:

```
<a href="#/wow/2">click it </a>
```

Why does that hash not end up in the URL or triggering a $(window).hashchange event?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

trigger("click") fires the onclick event handler, it is not the same as a person actually clicking.

example:  http://jsfiddle.net/dffsC/